# Images move slightly to the right on hover?

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with both my hover and active states for some of my buttons.

[image]

The buttons you see above move slightly to the right when you either hover or make it active. My arrow buttons however work fine.

Here is my CSS code for the middle buttons:

```
div.clean_rounded-horizontal.st_sliding_active >div.st_tabs{overflow:visible}

div.clean_rounded-horizontal >div.st_tabs div.st_tabs_wrap{position:relative !important;width:100%}

div.clean_rounded-horizontal.st_sliding_active >div.st_tabs div.st_tabs_wrap{width:auto !important;margin:0px 49px}

div.clean_rounded-horizontal >div.st_tabs ul{width:10000px;margin:0px;padding:0px;list-style:none}

div.clean_rounded-horizontal >div.st_tabs ul li{display:block;float:left;margin:0px}

div.clean_rounded-horizontal >div.st_tabs ul li a{color:#98d1e9;display:block;height:50px;text-decoration: none;text-align:center;width:90px;font:bold 12px/50px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background:url("http://i52.photobucket.com/albums/g25/AniM3Fr3aK/portbuttons_zps914fad15.png~original") no-repeat}

div.clean_rounded-horizontal >div.st_tabs ul li a:hover{background-position:center -51px;}

div.clean_rounded-horizontal >div.st_tabs ul li a.st_tab_first{}div.clean_rounded-horizontal.st_sliding_active >div.st_tabs ul li a.st_tab_first{border-left:0 none;border-top-left-radius:0px}

div.clean_rounded-horizontal >div.st_tabs ul li a.st_tab_last{}

div.clean_rounded-horizontal.st_sliding_active >div.st_tabs ul li a.st_tab_last{border-right:0 none;border-top-right-radius:0px}

div.clean_rounded-horizontal >div.st_tabs ul li a.st_tab_active{background-position:center -51px;}
```

Thank you for the help, not sure why it's doing this.

Comment: post the html as well and put it all in a [**jsFiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net) so the problem is [reproduced for us](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I was going to but I figured it out. I'm writing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. for some reason when I center it, it goes a bit to the right. So to fix it I have to change the center to a left. Like so

```
div.clean_rounded-horizontal >div.st_tabs ul li a.st_tab_active{background-position:left -51px;}
```